# Error: group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql-server

What is wrong in this query? Despite so many posts about the same error I can't figure out what is wrong on following query.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(RI.INSS), D.TICKET_NUMBER, RI.TICKET_NBR, D.STATUS 
FROM
    [DBIC].[LoIC].[DEMAND] D
INNER JOIN
    [DBIC].[LoIC].[DEMAND_REQUEST_INTRODUCED] DRI ON D.ID = DRI.ID_DEMAND
INNER JOIN
    [DBIC].[LoIC].[REQUEST_INTRODUCED] RI ON RI.ID = DRI.ID_REQUEST_INTRODUCED
WHERE 
    D.STATUS = 'DONE'
GROUP BY 
    'RI.TICKET_NBR'
```

Comment: Grouping by a literal string is going to do nothing.

Comment: If I remove my literal stings then I have following error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Column 'DBIC.LoIC.DEMAND.TICKET_NUMBER' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.                                                                                                                      Can you say what is wrong on the querry?

Comment: you can only specify the column which is specified in the Group BY in your select. and cannot select columns D.TICKET_NUMBER and  D.STATUS unless you add them in Group By and you don't need to specify the column name within ' ' as mentioned by @Larnu

Answer (score 1):

Try this to start...

```
select count(RI.INSS), D.TICKET_NUMBER, RI.TICKET_NBR, D.STATUS from [DBIC].[LoIC].[DEMAND] D
  inner join [DBIC].[LoIC].[DEMAND_REQUEST_INTRODUCED] DRI on D.ID = DRI.ID_DEMAND
  inner join [DBIC].[LoIC].[REQUEST_INTRODUCED] RI on RI.ID = DRI.ID_REQUEST_INTRODUCED
  where D.STATUS = 'DONE'
GROUP  BY D.TICKET_NUMBER, RI.TICKET_NBR, D.STATUS
```